How can I perform a refresh and manipulate state using AWS CDK?
With Terraform, I have used e.g. terraform state ..., terraform import ..., and terraform taint to manipulate the state.
With AWS CDK, I only see an option to import existing resources into the CloudFormation stack:
cdk import [STACK]
Currently, I'm facing an issue, where AWS CDK (CloudFormation) believes an S3 bucket exists, which it doesn't, as it was removed manually. Terraform would detect this, as it performs a "refresh" on terraform plan and terraform apply. Furthermore, with Terraform I would be able to remove the S3 bucket from the state manually using terraform state rm ....
How can I make AWS CDK perform a refresh and manipulate state manually?

Change the logical id of the bucket and it will recreate it.

Thank you, but I don't like that approach, as it requires the modification of IaC files, which I would rather avoid

The equivalent of a "state refresh" in CloudFormation is Drift detection. It has to be triggered manually, check the docs here.
CloudFormation does not remediate drift automatically - you'd have to do that manually by importing the bucket into the stack.
Not all resources support drift detection and import, but S3 Buckets support both. You can check the list of supported resources here.
Another solution that @kichik suggested in the comments would also work - triggering any change that would result in a resource replacement (like changing the construct ID) would force CloudFormation to create a new resource.

Thank you. By "you'd have to do that manually by importing the bucket into the stack.", you mean I should manually create and import the bucket into the stack?

I don't like @kichik's suggestion, as I have to modify the IaC to change the logical ID, which would also result in a new name of the bucket (unless I specify the bucket name explicitly)

Objectively, ins't AWS CDK a bit inferior to Terraform in terms of state management and automatic drift detection? I like AWS CDK for its pure approach to IaC, where I actually define infrastructure as code imperatively (not declaratively)

Yes, CloudFormation (not AWS CDK, because it just synthesizes into cloudformation) doesn't have flexible state management features like terraform.

Thank you. Do you know why that isn't the case? Isn't this a major deficit of CloudFormation that affects the adoption of AWS CDK?

Because it is a tradeoff between flexibility and safety, and AWS decided to favor the latter with CloudFormation.


you mean I should manually create and import the bucket into the stack?
Yes.


Sorry if off-topic, but in what sense is it safer?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
